# How can combine query in Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have implemented a REST web service in c#. To connect on database, I have used EntityFramework.

I have this code:

```
private IQueryable<ClinicalDocumentDTO> getClinicalDoc(string cf)
{
    if (cf != null)
    {
        return from p in db_data.CLINICAL_DOC
           where p.CodiceFiscaleAssisito == cf
           select new ClinicalDocumentDTO()
           //select new CLINICAL_DOC
           {
               Code = p.Code,
               CodeSystem = p.CodeSystem,
               dateStart = ad.VerifyEffectiveTime,
               dateEnd = ad.VerifyEffectiveTimeMax
           }
    }
}
```

Now I want to change this code, I have this field "dateStard" and "dateEnd", but on the database, I have three column (effetiveTime, effetiveTimeMin, effectiveTimeMax).

I want this:

```
if (effectiveTime == null) then
   dateStart= effectiveTimeMin,
   dateEnd = effectiveTimeMax
```

How can I do this in Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `?:` operator in select as mentioned below:

```
    return from p in db_data.CLINICAL_DOC
       where p.CodiceFiscaleAssisito == cf
       select new ClinicalDocumentDTO()
       //select new CLINICAL_DOC
       {
           Code = p.Code,
           CodeSystem = p.CodeSystem,
           dateStart = p.effectiveTime == null ? effectiveTimeMin : ad.VerifyEffectiveTime,
           dateEnd = p.effectiveTime == null ? effectiveTimeMax: ad.VerifyEffectiveTimeMax
       }
```

PS: casing of variables is not checked. Please updated them accordingly.